# Regualr expresion in groovy for find files

Tags: regex, groovy

I need to write regular expression with will found all files in folder witch ended with word: "groovy", for example 123groovy.txt.

I try to use it:

```
        dir.eachFileMatch(~/[groovy.]/) {file ->
        println file.name
    }
```

But it doesn't work

This folder for test:

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `dir.eachFileMatch(~/groovy\.[a-z]+$/)`

Comment: No, It isn't work. I don't get any result.

Comment: And if you double escape the dot? `dir.eachFileMatch(~/groovy\\.[a-z]+$`

Comment: Like this: dir.eachFileMatch(~/groovy\\.[a-z]+$/) {
    it -> print(it)
}. No it also doesn't work

Comment: If you have to match the whole line, then perhaps `.*groovy\.\w+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for the letters *before* groovy

```
        dir.eachFileMatch(~/.+?[gG]roovy.+/) {file ->
```

Answer (score 1):

See what `[groovy.]` matches:

```java
 [groovy.]                any character of: 'g', 'r', 'o', 'o', 'v',  'y', '.'
```

Use

```
dir.eachFileMatch(FileType.FILES, ~/.*groovy\.[^.]*$/, { println it.name })
```

The regex MUST match the entire string.

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  groovy                   'groovy'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^.]*                    any character except: '.' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```